# Dropdown Panel displaying little bit away from the Dropdown Textbox Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using `Angular 15.1.3` and `Angular Material 14.0.4`

I have created a Dropdown `mat-select` for Timezone. The code for that is as below..

```
<mat-select *ngIf="editSettings" 
    color="primary"           
    formControlName="timeZone" 
    placeholder="Select a timezone"
    [(value)]="selectedTimeZone" panelClass="mat-select-panel override-11 override-12 override-13 override-14 override-15 override-16">  
    <mat-option *ngFor="let t of utcTimezoneList" [value]="t.value">{{t.text}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

On click of Dropdown, when it is at the bottom of the page, then the panel displays upwards like below. But when the Dropdown is at the top of the page, then it displays properly.

[image: Timezone]

I have set the styles in the `styles.scss` file as below...

```
.mat-select-panel, .custom-panel-timezone.override-11.override-12.override-13.override-14.override-15.override-16 {
  margin: 95px 0px 95px 0px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

How to display panel aligned to the Dropdown textbox, whenever the user clicks on it?

**EDIT**

I have modified the css as below and now this is fixed when the Dropdown control is at the bottom. But when the Dropdown control is in the middle of the page, then it is overlapping the Dropdown Textbox

```
.mat-select-panel, custom-panel-timezone.override-1.override-2.override-3 {
  transform: translateY(-95px);
}
```

**SECOND EDIT**

Because I am using the same `.mat-select-panel` in `styles.scss` file, it is affecting the other controls.

Another reason is that gap is coming because I am using `95px` for the Dropdown style. If I decrease it to `38px` it is aligning properly. But when the Dropdown control is in the middle of the page, it is overlapping with the textbox.

Comment: I can suggest wrap this "mat-select" inside "mat-form-field" and let me know if that is resolved.
It would be great to share stackblitz URL so that able to fix that quickly

Comment: Still it is not working..

Comment: @CPK_2011 When you remove this CSS does it work fine?

Comment: Yeah, it works fine. But just overlaps the Dropdown Textbox.

Comment: @CPK_2011 For this one go for the transform solution we already spoke about, something in the body is interfering with the dropdown, but you will get issues when the dropdown opens up

Comment: Updated the Question with `EDIT`. Please look into it.

Comment: I found the root-cause of the problem. Explained in the `SECOND EDIT` of the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `disableOptionCentering` to the `mat-select` and after that it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just update angular material to v15, by default it will not overlap the dropdown textbox.